# android keeping package signature

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

i create mobile application and i published without proguard obfuscate
this app can download new version and  update automatically. 
thats all fine

now i fuscate my app with proguard now when app download new version and want to install it say Application not installed (Pakage with that name 
and different signature already installed)

i use command blow :
 -keepattributes Signature but nothings changed...

what can i do for it?
how can protect application signature after fuscated?

Comment: hv u changed the activity name?

Comment: no i didnt change activity name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you make sure to sign it with the same private key that you used before you obfuscated it? If you used a different key, Android will see it as a different app. [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: i am copy my app from bin folder in my project and now i am use export... i think this will change signature... how can i use old signature with exporting?

Comment: Do you know where the keystore file is that you used to sign the app before you uploaded it to the Play Store? If you use the same keystore to sign the obfuscated app it should be seen as the same app.

Comment: keystore generated automatically with ADT, i think it is in .android folder "debug.keystore" but how can update expire date? because in documente say expire date is 365 day after creation, and this keystore is it secure?

Comment: The debug keystore is only supposed to be used for debugging and not for actual distribution of your app. You should sign your app with your own private key made either during the eclipse export process or separately with the keystore tool that comes with the JDK. Google recommends that your keystore have an expiration date of more than 25 years.